# Accessing an iteration value with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, loops, properties

New to JSP, so still learning the functionality. I assume I am being handed a list of values and that list is being iterated with HTML code being output with the value of the property of the current iteration. I am trying to get the current property and check to see if the value matches what I am searching, and if it does, perform some action.

The original .jsp code:

```
<select name="userInfo.state">
    <option class="js_default_option">State</option>
    <s:iterator value="@com.homeservices.action.utils.StateCode@values()">
        <option value='<s:property/>'><s:property/></option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

What I want to do:

```
<select name="userInfo.state">
    <option class="js_default_option">State</option>
    <s:iterator value="@com.homeservices.action.utils.StateCode@values()">
        <% if(s:property == "Value") { %>
            <option value='<s:property/>' disabled><s:property/></option>
        <% } %>
        <option value='<s:property/>'><s:property/></option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

Comment: Careful with the statement _being iterated with HTML code_. HTML is markup, it is not executable.

Comment: Is this standard JSP?  I've never seen `@` used this way in a JSP.  What taglib is `s:`?

Comment: @tieTYT It's struts' iterator.

Comment: The taglib is defined in the beginning of the document using struts.
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

Answer (score 0):

The struts iterator documentation is [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator.html). You can use the `var` attribute to hold a reference to the current iterator element.

```
<s:iterator var="element" value="@com.homeservices.action.utils.StateCode@values()"> // i'm not sure about the whole @... part
```

You can now use `${element}` (or `#element` in struts' tags) to reference each current iteration element.

Please don't use scriplets in your jsp. Use JSTL or struts' tag libraries.